# lxml installion with pip leads to an error

Tags: python, installation, ascii, pip

I am trying to install lxml on Centos 6 with pip2.7 (Python 2.7) and I land on an error. Has anyone found a solution to it? I am not using any framework with it like a lot of people have landed on this issue with some other java package etc.. I have issue with python/pip specifically.

```
 Cleaning up...
    Command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_user/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FHRyQv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_user/lxml
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip2.7", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip2.7')()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
        return command.main(cmd_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
        text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
    [user@user tests]$
```

Comment: What's your `echo $LANG` shows?

Comment: output of echo $LANG is "en_US.utf8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install lxml` after:

```
yum install libevent-devel python-devel libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
```

Comment: Wilbeibi - When i did the yum install, I get a message saying those 2 packages are there and when i do pip after it, I get the same error.

Comment: Hmm.. It also might related to your memory. Are you sure you have enough memory?

Comment: will `yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel` works?

Comment: @Wilbeibi yes if you already have the libevent and python development package installed. however yum would just ignore the already installed packages so just copypasta anyways.